# c++ subclasses and operator= : infinite loops and unexpected calls

Tags: c++, inheritance

The following code goes to infinite loop.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
   public:
      A(){
         cout << "Normal constructor" << endl;
      }
      A(const A& moo){
         cout << "It's a constructor!" << endl;
         operator=(moo);
      }
      void operator=(const A& moo){
         cout << "Calling A::Operator=" << endl;
      }
};

class B : public A{
   public:
      B(){}
      B(const A& thea){
         cout << "Gotshere" << endl;
         operator=(thea);
      }
};


int main(){

   B b;

   b = A();

}
```

The output of the infinite loop cycles between "Normal constructor" and "Gotshere". I'm guessing from the `main` function that when assigning an `A` to a `B` class, it tries to call `B::operator=`, which doesn't exist, so it calls `B(const A&)` again, instead.

What I don't get is why `A()` is called. Does anyone know? **EDIT** should have made this clear, `A()` is called **repeatedly** on the infinite loop.

Of course, the fix is to put `B::operator=(const A&)`, but I'd love to know why it's doing that.

Furthermore, I added an operator for class `B`:

```
void B::operator=(const A&) { cout << "That should fix things. A::Operator=" << endl; }
```

And it did fix things, but when I do `B b; b = B()`, I get `Calling A::operator=` instead of the output for `B::operator='. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

> What I don't get is why A() is called. Does anyone know?

`B` inherits `A`, so before constructing `B`, `A` component of `B` must be constructed. Since you are not specifying which constructor of `A` you wish to call, compiler chooses the default one.

**EDIT** (in response to the edit of the question)

As far as calling `A` repeatedly part is concerned, here is where your logic is wrong: you said

> it tries to call `B::operator=`, which doesn't exist, so it calls B(const A&) again, instead.

but this is not what is going on: it is not calling `A`'s operator `=`, it calls `B`'s operator `=` that the compiler has gratuitously generated for you. To verify, change the line to `A::operator=(thea);`, and the infinite recursion will disappear.

So why an infinite recursion then? Recall that the signature of the generated assignment operator is

```
B& operator=(const B& b)
```

Compiler needs an instance of `B` to pass to the `operator=`, but you are passing an instance of `A`. However, you defined a constructor of `B` that takes `const A&`. This is sufficient for the compiler to produce the correct call by creating a temporary B, constructing it from `const A&`, and calling `B::operator=`, like this:

```
B temp(thea); <<== At this point, you're in an infinite recursion
B::operator=(temp);
```

On a side note, assignment in C++ is an lval, so your overload of the assignment operator should be returning, by reference, the object being assigned to (i.e. `*this`).

```
A& operator=(const A& moo){
    cout << "Calling A::Operator=" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I get that, but what I should have made clear is I'm wondering why A() is called **repeatedly**?

Answer (score 2):

B::operator= takes a B&, but you are passing it an A&, so it has to construct a new B from the A, which causes the infinite recursion.

As for your second question.  You defined B::operator=(const A &), but an assignment operator that takes a const B & is still automatically generated, and the automatically generated assignment operator calls the base assignment operator.